# Get header image of news post

Tags: steam, steam-web-api

I'm trying to get header image of news post.

Here URL of a post: https://steamcommunity.com/games/252490/announcements/detail/2918859255896819280

Header image URL I'm trying to get: https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/clans/5377070/955c1eeddc5603be7cea65adb1921751e18c3f77.png

I tried to request this API URL: https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamNews/GetNewsForApp/v2/?appid=252490&feed=steam_community_announcements

But it's doesn't include header image in json for some reason. Is there any other way I can get a header image?

Comment: Did You try a GET request to the CDN. The "cdn" in the second link is an acronym for Content Delivery Network. It is kinda what they do.

Comment: @NathanToulbert How would I get id for image in cdn url? `955c1eeddc5603be7cea65adb1921751e18c3f77` it's different for every news post

Comment: However you got your hands on the middle URI above, keep doing it for each image that you need, recursively, i guess. If you do not have access to the image ids then you dont even have the endpoint id, in which case you do not even have a target. How do you request a resource that you do not know you need?

Comment: @NathanToulbert I inspected steam page in browser to get it. How would I do it in node.js without 3rd party packages. And even if I can do it web-scraping is definitely not a consistent way to get image, if steam decides to update that page design my code will break. I was hoping there is better way to get header image, for example through some other API endpoint I'm not aware about.

Comment: You need to Know what you're looking for. Are you actually building a client, or are you just trying to educate yourself. am asking because it depends completely on the context. I cant give  a specific answer because I don't have the specifics of the question For example, are you just gonna pull Random pics, or do you have constraints of some type.

Comment: @henroper did you found solution?

Comment: @rendom nope :(